# How to create multipart line and polygon with interior ring in arcgisscripting?

Tags: arcpy, geometry, polygon-creation, polyline-creation

My objective is to swap X,Y coordinates of feature classes using Python and arcgisscripting.

Based on help examples, I managed to write script which reads and writes all geometry types.

The problem is with polyline geometry: for multipart lines, all parts are connected and they should be disjoint. It seems that connection between last vertex of one part is connected with first vertex of next part.
*It's strange especially as script deals well with multipart polygons and polygons with void.*

Am I missing something with multipart polyline geometry?

```
import arcgisscripting
gp = arcgisscripting.create(9.3)

gp.overwriteoutput = True
gp.workspace = r"D:\Work\SwapXY.gdb"
inFC = r"D:\Work\SwapXY.gdb\Line"

desc = gp.Describe(inFC)
shapeField = desc.ShapeFieldName  #SHAPE field name
shapeType = desc.ShapeType

# Create FC for inserting swaped geometries (if not exist)
...

try:
    rows = gp.SearchCursor(inFC) #open SearchCursor on input FC
    row = rows.next()
    outRows = gp.InsertCursor(outFC) #open InsertCursor on output FC

    #create Array object which will contain features vertices (other than points)
    vertexArray = gp.CreateObject("Array")

    while row:
        feature = row.getValue(shapeField) #get the SHAPE field into variable

        ##For point geometry there is another way of reading coordinates than for polyline/polygon
        if shapeType.upper() == "POINT" or shapeType.upper() == "MULTIPOINT":
           #this part works right

        else:
            #feature can have multiple parts - first goes iteration through parts
            partNum = 0
            partCount = feature.PartCount
            while partNum < partCount:
                part = feature.GetPart(partNum) #the output is Array of points
                pnt = part.next() #take first point from Array of points

                #iterate through all points in array
                while pnt:
                    #for each geometry create new POINT obj and assign swapped Y, X. Then add vertices to ARRAY
                    vertex = gp.CreateObject("Point")
                    vertex.X = pnt.Y
                    vertex.Y = pnt.X
                    vertexArray.add(vertex)
                    pnt = part.next()

                    #If pnt is null, either the part is finished or there is an interior ring
                    if not pnt:
                        pnt = part.next()
                        if pnt:
                            print "Interior:"

                partNum += 1

            newFeature = outRows.newRow()
            newFeature.shape = vertexArray       #assign ARRAY filled with points to shape field
            outRows.insertRow(newFeature)              

            vertexArray.RemoveAll() #clear ARRAY before processing new geometry

        row = rows.next()
except:
    print gp.GetMessages()
```

---

In fact script doesn't work for polygons with more than one interior ring. So the problem is wider than I thought.
In polygon case, I've found that null point between exterior and interior rings should be inserted. But when `gp.CreateObject("Point")` is inserted, a point with coordinates (0,0) is added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As adding null point as it was suggested [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/14952/arcgis-10-0-arcpy-how-to-create-a-polygon-geometry-from-inner-and-outer-ring-po) gave a point with (0,0) cordinates, I searched existing scripts in ESRI repository and I've found another way of separating polygon rings as well as polyline parts.
The solution is based on creating two arrays: `featureVertexArray` for storing whole geometry and `partVertexArray` for storing separate rings:

```
try:
    rows = gp.SearchCursor(inFC) #open SearchCursor on input FC
    row = rows.next()
    outRows = gp.InsertCursor(outFC) #open InsertCursor on output FC

    #create Array object which will contain features vertices
    featureVertexArray = gp.CreateObject("Array")
    partVertexArray = gp.CreateObject("Array")

    while row:
        feature = row.getValue(shapeField) #get the SHAPE field into variable
        vertex = gp.CreateObject("Point") #empty Point object to store geometry

        ##For point geometry there is another way of reading coordinates than for polyline/polygon
        if shapeType.upper() == "POINT" or shapeType.upper() == "MULTIPOINT":
            #this part works right

        else:
            #feature can have multiple parts - first goes iteration through parts
            partNum = 0
            partCount = feature.PartCount
            while partNum < partCount:
                part = feature.GetPart(partNum) #the output is Array of points
                pnt = part.next() #take first point from Array of points

                #iterate through all points in array
                while pnt:
                    #for each geometry create new POINT obj and assign swapped Y, X. Then add vertices to ARRAY
                    vertex.X, vertex.Y = pnt.Y, pnt.X
                    partVertexArray.add(vertex)
                    pnt = part.next()

                    #If pnt is null, either the part is finished or there is an interior ring
                    if not pnt:
                        pnt = part.next()
                        featureVertexArray.add(partVertexArray)
                        partVertexArray.removeAll()
                        #if pnt:
                            #print "Interior:"

                featureVertexArray.add(partVertexArray)
                partNum += 1 #increment part number to run loop

            newFeature = outRows.newRow()   #create new row in InsCur
            newFeature.shape = featureVertexArray       #assign ARRAY filled with points to shape field
            outRows.insertRow(newFeature)   #insert new row                

        featureVertexArray.removeAll() #clear ARRAYS before processing new geometry
        partVertexArray.removeAll()

        row = rows.next()
```