# Create a shapefile from geometry

Tags: arcpy, shapefile, polygon-creation, create

Please excuse my lingo, I am still learning some aspects of geo spatial and arcpy.

I have a python script that takes a shapefile. The shapefile consists of a polyline. I have traversed the polyline, done some interpolation and retrieved some points. Long story short, I'm trying to generate polygons along the polyline based on intervals of the M values. These polygons have four points (my geometries).

How can I take these geometries, or points, that are in my python script and output them into a shapefile. I know I'll have to pass my points to a function that produces a shapefile, but that is my dilemma. How exaclty do I create the function that creates my shapefile for the geometries?

Comment: I added the [tag:polygon-creation] tag to help you find related threads. A [search](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/polygon-creation+arcgis+python) turns up some promising ones, especially the Python code found at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/21443/how-to-create-multipart-line-and-polygon-with-interior-ring-in-arcgis-python. Would that perhaps answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

[Create a new `Polyline` object, then use `CopyFeatures`](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//000v000000n2000000).

```
import arcpy
coords = [(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6), (7, 8)]
ar = arcpy.Array()
for x, y in coords:
    ar.add(arcpy.Point(x, y))
polyline = arcpy.Polyline(ar)
arcpy.management.CopyFeatures(polyline, r"c:\path\to\my\new.shp")
```

Comment: THis seems to work perfectly as far as outputting a shapefile. I wasn't aware that it'd create the projection file, an xml file, etc. If I needed to store other information in regards to the polyline (perhaps the type or something of that sort) can I alter the above code to have this information stored in one of the created files?

Comment: If you needed to add additional fields, etc, it'd be a little more complex and involve a call to `CreateFeatureclass` and as many `AddField` calls as necessary to get the columns you'd need, and then an `InsertCursor` to insert the values.

Comment: The additional fields would be information pertaining to the polygon such as the M value at certain intervals. I'd need to store this value and a few other values in the .dbf file. Using CreateFeatureClass should help me accomplish this, correct?

Comment: Yes. CreateFeatureclass will let you enable M or Z and adding other values will require additional columns with AddField calls.

Comment: I'm having some difficulty completing this. The values that I am trying to add to the .dbf file are values that are passed into the function. I shouldn't neccesarily need a cursor for that. And I think AddField is a little overkill for this scenario

Comment: Please add more information (Your script? The data you're feeding in?) to this question or post a new one.

Comment: based on the code above that was posted: I'm not sure how to store these geometries (along with some other information) and write them to the .dbf file. I was thinking of using a dictionary but can the array be used as well? If I keep looping through the process will the "ar.add()" function allow me to keep adding to the shapefile before I actually create the shapefile? Hope I'm making sense here

Comment: def CreateShapeFile(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h, TotalPages):
    
        coords = [(a,e), (b,f), (c,g), (d,h), (a,e)]
        ar = arcpy.Array()
    
        
        for x,y in coords:
            ar.add(arcpy.Point(x,y))
        polygon = arcpy.Polyline(ar)

# Last line goes outside of loop

        arcpy.management.CopyFeatures(polygon, r"c:\temp\myshapefile26.shp")

I need to loop through this to capture/store multiple geometries.